# Generate script from Handbrake preset

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, media, handbrake

Is it possible to generate a script/command to run from a Handbrake preset or from the queue on OS X?

Like take the queue and generate a command I can run in terminal instead of through the GUI?  (Either with ffmpeg or with HandBrakeCLI)

Comment: Yes it is. Exported queue (`*.hbq`) files and the presets file (`presets.xml`/`user_presets.xml`) are both simple XML files. All you need is to parse them and apply the commands to either `HandBrakeCLI` or 'translate' them into `ffmpeg` commands.

Comment: Yes, I actually have my handbrake CLI script within a windows `.bat` file. You need to use the Handbrake CLI syntax so when run in command line Handbrake can run it. I basically create a preset in Handbrake and then reference that preset along with other tweaks in the `.bat` file so i can run as a batch, command line. See the Handbrake CLI Guide: https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-guide.html